# How To Stop Firefox Tabs From Auto-Refreshing on Tab Switch

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using Firefox 14.0.1. When I have multiple tabs open, and I switch from one tab to the next, the tab I select "auto refreshes" the content. This is extremely annoying, especially when I'm writing a blog post, etc. Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: Does this happen always?

Comment: Only one thing that I can think of: when you start Firefox and restore previous session Firefox won't load all tabs immediately by default, only when you switch to the tab for the first time. If however you really see a refresh every time - try disabling your extensions.

Comment: I had something similar with `TabMixPlus` plugin installed (an older version) and auto-update accidentally turned on.

Answer (score 5):

In `about:config` set `accessibility.blockautorefresh` to `true`.

Comment: Tabs auto-reloading in July 2019 (FFver67.0, on Win7 laptop) even though this blockautorefresh switch was already set to true.

Comment: July 2019: see [here](https://www.askvg.com/fix-mozilla-firefox-automatically-suspends-tabs-and-reloads-when-you-visit/) for how to stop firefox dumping tab content to prevent memory hogging.

Comment: A year late, but a lot of the time, that means some tab is leaking and you should open System Monitor, Task Manager or whatever and kill the hogs.

Answer (score 0):

## Firefox - about:config

So, here are several steps to try to **Stop** auto-refreshing tabs in Firefox. We'll go by Searching and Applying certain parameters in **about:config** section of Firefox.
These changes may breack many "automated", "fresh" and "up-to-date" content delivery mechanisms of Firefox, so beware - it'll take some line editing, at your own risk! Backup your data before proceeding!

### Overall logic looks like this:

**Step 1.**
First, we need to switch *from* **autorefresh** to **"on-tab-click"** refresh schema ( *_on_demand feature*) being initially triggered during Firefox startup. *Search for, and change to:*

```
browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand : true
browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs_on_demand : true
```

**Step 1.1**
At this point, you may Load and Pin all Tabs *(websites)* necessary for your work, and activate **"Work Oflline"** mode, at this poin Firefox will think that there is no Internet, thus - there is nowhere to autorefresh / update data from; and **"on-tab-click"** event **shouldn't trigger** any **auto-refreshings**.
On the other hand, modern websites have many **DOM** and **JS** features built up with "auto-refreshability" in mind, and may or may not work in Offline Mode as you normally expect.
*Plus, you may find useful these about:config search results to fine-tune your work in Offline Mode:*

```
tab 
browser.tab 
browser.cache
browser.cache.offline.enable : true
```

If Everything works as expected **in "Offline Mode"** - well done, you've made it! Now you can do all the stuff you need, surf through open tabs with **no "on-tab-click" auto-reload events being triggered** *(this will only work untill you close specific Tab or Close Firefox entirely, as session and cache data will be lost in whole or in part).*
Finish and save all your work progress before getting back Online (save data out of the browser), because Page may refresh itself immediately after you disable Offline Mode, and not every website has Auto-save option built in !

**But, if you need those Tabs to stay Online and surf back and forth with ALL "on-tab-click" auto-reload events disabled - proceed to Step 2, still that may not always work as expected!**

**Step 2.**
Now, we'll try to find and disable "on-system-event", "on-page", "on-tab", "on-content-change" and several other features, so that in return - **"on-tab-click" refresh** configs *become* ***non invokeable*** in **Online Mode** (in terms of native Firefox presets).
Remember about websites' own DOM and JS auto-reload features that may be immutable in most cases!

```
browser.tabs
// read and decide //
browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory : false
browser.tabs.loadInBackground : false

browser.sessionstore
browser.sessionstore.debug : true
browser.sessionstore.debug.no_auto_updates : true
browser.sessionstore.restore_hidden_tabs : false

browser.zoom.updateBackgroundTabs : false

accessibility
// Disable accessibility features if you don't use them !
accessibility.blockautorefresh : true
```

**Step 3.**
Cleanup/delete url (string) entries that may send update requests to Firefox and other servers:

```
browser.search
browser.safebrowsing 
app.update
```

**Step 4.**
Close **about:config** tab, Pin one or two tabs *(leave other tabs unpinned)*; make sure that **"Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload the page"** and **"Show my windows and tabs from last time"** settings are activated in Firefox Options Menu; then -  fully Close Firefox browser. Wait for about 30 sec. for all background processes and savings to complete.
Then Start Firefox again and check the difference in tabs behaviour. **Worked for me on Firefox 52.9 ESR, OS Windows.**

### General remarks:

**a)** if your Firefox version or OS are different, try more generalised search terms to find relevant configs:

```
e10s : false
accessibility : false
multiprocess : false
refresh : false  
restore : false  
update : false  
dom : false
Background : false
```

**b)** in those search results, try setting some number (integer) parameters to  -  " 360000 " or more (read and decide), so that automatic refresh / update confs aren't triggered so often.

**c)** If mentioned configs are not present in your version of Firefox, try switching to Firefox ESR or Dev branch, to make these settings work for you.